# Clone after initial Push?

Tags: git

If I just performed an initial push to my new git repo (git push -u origin master), I assume I need to set my local code as a working copy by performing a clone right after?   Or is it basically already "cloned" or what I mean is it's already flagged as a "working copy" after performing your first push since this is to a new repo I created..not an existing? Just want to be sure, I'm fairly new to Git.

Comment: hmm, hard to understand, could you write some lines of code to let us know where you're at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start explaining, I need you to understand what 3 branches are at work here:

- Local `master`
- Remote `master` (at `origin`)
- Local `origin/master` (a local "reflection" of a remote `master`, typically not for direct use)

Before you pushed, you only had a local `master` and nothing else, empty remote.

```
git push -u origin master
```

This attempts to push your local `master` branch to a remote branch with the same name (`master`) in remote repository called `origin` (a common name for a remote, even used by default when cloning).

If successful, Git creates a new local branch called `origin/master` and sets your local `master` to "track changes" (because of `-u` as in "upstream") to `origin/master`: any changes to that branch are assumed as "should be merged into `master` as well".

This is only important when you'll be `pull`ing down the changes from your remote repository. When you're on a `master` branch, it will first fetch commits to `origin/master`, and then examine what branch `master` is tracking. Having found `origin/master` it would attempt to `merge` it with your local `master`. `pull` does quite a lot inside.

After this your local `master` and `origin/master` should be on the same commit and your remote `master` should look exactly the same as your local one. So you shouldn't need to do anything.

To understand branching better, I strongly recommend **[this interactive tutorial](https://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this right, you're now in the `alread "cloned"` state:

If you successfully ran a `git push -u origin master` then you ran it from the local repository.

By providing the `-u` option to the push, git will remember that your branch is meant to track the one on `origin`, which is similar to what you get by cloning a remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to clone anything on the machine that you've pushed from.  You've essentially have a clone of the remote repository; it just happens to be the case that it's the exact same as your local repository.

When you clone a repository, that implies that you *don't* have the code currently present on your machine.  In your scenario, you already have the code, so you don't need to do any cloning.

Comment: yea just wanted to be sure...but yea cloning is for existing your'e right